# how to print only checked picture on webpage?

Tags: javascript, printing, html

I want to print only checked picture on webpage.

this is my js.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#print").one('click', function(ev){
        $('#main').prepend('<center><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="print2">복사하기</button></center>')
        $('.post').prepend('<input type="checkbox">');
        $("#print2").on('click', function(){
            var images ='';
            $('li').each(function(){
                var thisCheckFlag=$(this).children('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked');
                if(thisCheckFlag){
                images+='<img src ="'+$(this).find('img').attr('src')+'"><br>';
                }
            });
            if(images){
                var myWindow=window.open('','printWindow','width=800,height=800');
                myWindow.document.write(
                '<html><head><title>Print</title></head><body>'
                +images+'</body></html>'
                );
                myWindow.focus();
                myWindow.print();
            }
            else alert('먼저 선택하세요.');
        });
        ev.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

it is correctly work. but if i do not choose any picture, i want to show alert. it doesn't work. if i do not choose any picture and then click print(id=print2) it show the web page as blow.
[image]

what is problem? TT I can't find error.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to only print checked image, I think you can achieve it by using css only.
Did you already try something like this? (maybe need some adjustment depending on you DOM tree)

```
@media print {
   img, input {
      display: none;
   }
   input:checked + img {
      display: block;
   }
}
```

`@media print` will only target printer